# VB6 auto completion (intellisense) is suddenly taking forever

Tags: vb6, autocomplete, intellisense

VB6 just added a new "feature" right out of the blue: every time I
declare a variable, property or function, when I reach the "as"
keyword, VB has a fit and hogs the cpu for almost a minute.

Anyone knows what this might be? I turned off all plugins (AxTools,
MzTools), restarted VB, rebooted, and still nothing.

This is incredibly annoying, and there's no way I can get anything
done this way. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: How big is the project?  Have you created any class modules in your current project?  Is this on all projects, or only in the current project?

Comment: Quite big.
Yes, a bunch of them.
Apparently, only on the current one.

Comment: If it's only the current project I would guess it's some weirdness for a component that you're only referencing in the current project? Have a look at Project-References and Project-Components. Anything shown as missing? Anything unusual that you're not using in the other projects where this isn't happening? Can you try the project on another computer and see whether the same happens there?

Comment: VB6!! Amazing!  That tool is 11 years old! That is an eternity in development technology.  Amazing that it is still viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd get a copy of Sysinternals [Filemon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx) utility (or [Procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) if it's appropriate) and see if you can figure out which files VB6's Intellisense is accessing.  Then I would rename then to different names so the VB6 intellisense mechanism might re-create them and see if that fixes anything.  Just a suggestion.

Comment: I think in this case SI RegMon is more appropriate as the types are referenced through OLE registration.

Comment: Thanks for that correction @MaSuGaNa.  I did not know that the intellisense information was accessed via OLE.

Comment: In fact Regmon has been replaced by ProcMon for modern versions of Windows, so you were correct to recommend ProcMon - it's just that you should look at the registry not the files. "FileMon and RegMon have been replaced by Process Monitor on versions of Windows starting with Windows 2000 SP4, Windows XP SP2, Windows Server 2003 SP1, and Windows Vista. FileMon and RegMon remain for legacy operating system support, including Windows 9x."